# When using a database first approach in entity framework (scaffolding) Is the HasKey.HasName("PK_123ABC") ignored?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When scaffolding from a database, in the OnModelCreating fluent builder the primary keys are being created with the HasName property added:

```
entity.HasKey(e => e.AttachFileId)
                .HasName("PK__TableName__S34F3453GHJ");
```

The database has been deleted and recreated in the database several times and as you can imagine the key name is randomized each time.  So far when running the app I have never had any issues targeting this table with the foreign key. (even though it doesn't match the one in the database)

I could remove it, however other people may end up scaffolding again and it is always created this way by default.

(Also F.Y.I) this app will always be database first, and there is no option to go code first in this scenario.

So when using database first is this property always ignored? Can I safely assume it will continue to be ignored when the app runs as long as no migrations are performed?

Thanks!

Comment: If you aren't going to create new migrations, which would need to know the PK name to drop / recreate it, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that the system will always use a database-first approach, then you need to manage constraint names on the database side.

Back in the day I have written a script for uniform renaming of PKs, FKs, defauls and such, which I use since then. The relevant section (for PKs) looks like this:

```sql
/*
Primary keys

Pattern:
PK_[%SCHEMA%_]%TABLENAME%
*/

print 'print ''-- Primary keys'';
go
';

select N'exec sp_rename N' + quotename(sq.OldName, '''') + N', N' + quotename(sq.[NewName], '''') + N', N''INDEX'';
go
' as [-- Primary keys]
from (
    select object_name(parent_object_id) as [SortOrder], k.name as [ObjectName],
        quotename(object_schema_name(k.parent_object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(object_name(k.parent_object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(k.name) as [OldName],
        N'PK_' + case when schema_name(k.schema_id) != 'dbo' then object_schema_name(k.parent_object_id) + N'_' else N'' end + object_name(parent_object_id) as [NewName]
    from sys.key_constraints k
    where is_ms_shipped = 0
        and type_desc = 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
        and objectproperty(parent_object_id, 'IsUserTable') = 1
    ) sq
where sq.ObjectName != sq.[NewName]
order by sq.SortOrder;
go
```

This code doesn't rename anything by itself; rather, it generates the list of `sp_rename` calls that, when executed, do all the job.

You can make a habit of always running this code before committing changes to your database project (you source-control your database, for example with SSDT, right?..), and it will mitigate this and other similar issues.